# FireBase Filtering node base on combination key values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase node as follows

```
"accountEntries": {
"records" : {
    "-L6sVLAzVjPp7EU5FuWh" : {
       "filters" : {
        "-L6sVLB3Ko76l9xRDYRI" : "02-11-2018",
        "-L6sVLB4i-UCsJnUboIH" : "Second Customer",
        "-L6sVLB5EGGO9cl2h_K4" : "02-11-2018_Second Customer",
        "-L6sVLB7wevrdWLcVgDY" : "02-11-2018_Second Customer_cash",
        "-L6sVLB8ElLJRSPEbvEs" : "Second Customer_cash",
        "-L6sVLB9nBnVUtYQKoL8" : "cash",
        "-L6sVLBA8vZhSixrw73J" : "02-11-2018_cash"
      }
    },
    "-L6sVMFYOdIPIjhekxy0" : {
      "filters" : {
        "-L6sVMFcWR7Y6ADmSFrJ" : "02-14-2018",
        "-L6sVMFeGGxMbYLpQaim" : "Fourth Customer",
        "-L6sVMFhLbF_zF9b_rgl" : "02-14-2018_Fourth Customer",
        "-L6sVMFj4dW6pKQZVTR9" : "02-14-2018_Fourth Customer_cash",
        "-L6sVMFmB2iFC53TSYyE" : "Fourth Customer_cash",
        "-L6sVMFoYEE_MSPzrSHA" : "cash",
        "-L6sVMFq09fn2rqn3vV4" : "02-14-2018_cash"
      }
    },
    "-L6sVMy374a07w018-lT" : {
      "filters" : {
        "-L6sVMy857VluJe6G7-8" : "02-18-2018",
        "-L6sVMy9j_fIL9xJqfGq" : "Fourth Customer",
        "-L6sVMyBkPcpxS9CQev3" : "02-18-2018_Fourth Customer",
        "-L6sVMyDFlpMfvpD4Wbv" : "02-18-2018_Fourth Customer_cash",
        "-L6sVMyEKN3rnfptc24c" : "Fourth Customer_cash",
        "-L6sVMyHG0F2IMQVI9TY" : "cash",
        "-L6sVMyKj6I8i-idICE8" : "02-18-2018_cash"
      }
    },
    "-L6sVNmDGKqTJN7XsZmI" : {
      "filters" : {
        "-L6sVNmHZCeYtEBI_Vok" : "02-19-2018",
        "-L6sVNmIoR53aqW6Um0S" : "Fourth Customer",
        "-L6sVNmKk3PMAwrMYsPl" : "02-19-2018_Fourth Customer",
        "-L6sVNmMg9trmWeOBhSg" : "02-19-2018_Fourth Customer_cash",
        "-L6sVNmOQUuYMWWuxNnV" : "Fourth Customer_cash",
        "-L6sVNmRFoomegzHyi5_" : "cash",
        "-L6sVNmUzFjyShhJPDTa" : "02-19-2018_cash"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The Objective is to filter the records based on the filter node with the different combinations.

We have three filters Date,Customer Name and Type

If we want to filter on date then will check the filters value with

```
startAt('02-19-2018).endAt('02-19-2018')
```

If we want to filter  on customer then will check the filters value with

```
startAt('Fourth Customer').endAt('Fourth Customer')
```

If we want to filter  on type then will check the filters value with

```
startAt('cash').endAt('cash')
```

If we want to filter  on Date and Customer then will check the filters value with Date range = 02-11-2018 to 02-18-2018, Customers = "Second Customer", "Fourth Customer"

```
startAt('02-11-2018_Second Customer').endAt('02-18-2018_Fourth Customer')
```

i have the firebase code as below.

```
var startfilterKey="02-11-2018_Second Customer";
var endfilterKey = "02-18-2018_Fourth Customer";

var accountEntriesList= this.firebase.database.ref('/accountEntries/records').orderByChild('filters').startAt(startfilterKey).endAt(endfilterKey).limitToLast(10);

accountEntriesList.once('value',function(snapshot) { 
  if(snapshot){
     snapshot.forEach(childShapshot => {
     var key = childShapshot.key;
     accountEntriesKeyValue.push(key);
     return false;
  });
 }
});
```

The above code doesn't work as expected of filtering the node.

If i remove the endAt it gives all the nodes.

How to filter the nodes based on the filter key combination?